# Add to path only sh file not a dir

Tags: command-line, bash, execute-command

I have a bin folder with a bunch of sh files. For example "server-run.sh", "server-stop.sh", "server-do-something.sh". And I want to run file "server-stop.sh" from anywhere. I could add this bin folder to path but "run" and "do-something" files also will be available and I don't want to pollute my console. Also I don't want to add this file to /bin folder, because it could change. Maybe link. Can I somehow add only "server-stop.sh" to path?

Comment: It's worth noting that if you want to be able to run them without the `.sh`, just omit the `.sh` from the name. Extensions are meaningless to the Linux kernel, it's the hashbang (`#!`) that determines the program to call. Executable scripts do not usually have an extension in Linux, unlike libraries. And `.sh` is misleading if it's in fact a bash script.

Comment: (However, if you want to run your scripts from a graphical file manager, they will probably not recognize extensionless scripts.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way is to add a symbolic link to this file in the `/usr/local/bin` directory:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s server-stop.sh /path/to/your/folder/server-stop.sh
```

In this case, you are adding a link to the original file, so you can always change the original file and you command will always be working.

Comment: You should **not** use `/usr/bin` or `/bin` for locally compiled programs or your own scripts, those are reserved for packages. If you want to make it globally available, use `/usr/local/bin`, else just use `~/.local/bin` or similar.

Answer (score 4):

Creating links in `/usr/bin` works, but unless you want the scripts to be available for all users, I would prefer to create the links in `~/bin`, with the same result, but not touching the global system. Furthermore, OP has not mentioned where the scripts are stored. creating a link globally while the scripts are stored locally is bad practice, so alltogether I would suggest:

- Create a local directory `~/bin`.
- Remove the language extension from the scripts (unless they invoke each other), make them executable (see further below).
- Create links to the scripts from `~/bin` (ln -sf).
- Log out and back in.

Either with or without language extension, the script would work perfectly well. However, there are some arguments to use the script without language extension:

- For reasons of clarity, it might be preferable to name *the link to the script* similar to *the script itself*. keeping the language extension would then be less convenient when invoking the script.
- Although a bit overdone in cases of user-written scripts, according to [lintian conventions](http://lintian.debian.org/tags/script-with-language-extension.html), scripts (or links to scripts) in default searchpaths should not have a language extension. 
  -

Comment: Why are you recommending that the extensions be removed?

Comment: @terdon for reasons of clarity; I would want to name the link similar to the script. invoking with extension would then be inconvenient, and a bit "ugly".

Comment: OK, I _like_ having extensions as it tells me what the script is. This is just personal preference but I prefer my scripts with extensions.

Comment: @terdon That is of course true! It is just a script of course, and keeping the idea might be overdone, but isn't it unconventional to add language extensions in default searchpaths?

Comment: Not at all, quite the contrary actually. The convention is to have shell scripts with `.sh` extension and perl scripts with `.pl`, python with `py` etc. This is often not done for tools in `/usr/bin` but is usually the case for user-written files.

Comment: @terdon while packaging, I actually used to have language extensions, but always got the lintian complaint, until I removed it, see http://lintian.debian.org/tags/script-with-language-extension.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14043/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-terdon)

Comment: I apologize for continuing here, but I'd like to point out that the convention in the Unix/Linux world is actually **not** to have extensions for **executable** scripts. On the other hand, libraries/modules do tend to have extensions (`.so`, `.py`, `.pl`, etc.). However, users coming from Windows might add extensions to their executable scripts, especially since it's actually required for GUI file managers to recognize them.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the `bash` built-in command `hash` to remember the location of the `server-stop.sh` script:

```
hash -p /path/to/folder/server-stop.sh server-stop
```

Just add the above line to your `.bashrc` file.
You can now use `server-stop` everywhere in your `bash` shell/scripts.

See `help hash`:

```
hash: hash [-lr] [-p pathname] [-dt] [name ...]
Remember or display program locations.

Determine and remember the full pathname of each command NAME.  If
no arguments are given, information about remembered commands is displayed.

Options:
  -d        forget the remembered location of each NAME
  -l        display in a format that may be reused as input
  -p pathname   use PATHNAME is the full pathname of NAME
  -r        forget all remembered locations
  -t        print the remembered location of each NAME, preceding
        each location with the corresponding NAME if multiple
        NAMEs are given
Arguments:
  NAME      Each NAME is searched for in $PATH and added to the list
        of remembered commands.
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps an alias is what you are looking for. Open your `~/.bash_aliases` file and add the following to the end of the file(the file may be empty depending upon whether you have added an alias previously):

```
alias server-stop.sh='/path/to/your/server-stop.sh`
```

**Pros:**

- This will only add `server-stop.sh` as you intend to
- This won't change your `$PATH` variable
- Other users of your system are unaffected

**Cons:**

- You will have to change the alias once you change the path where `server-stop.sh` is located(I don't think that will be required very frequently)
- This will work only for bash shell, you will have to see what other shells use for alias.

Comment: Also good approach. Thanx.