# How to make a application/script available from Bash?

Tags: bash

If I want to launch a script (let's say in the home directory I have a file called `hi.py`) I need to specify the full path: `python /home/user/hi.py`. But when I want to use `mkdir` I can simply say: `mkdir folder_name`. How can I do the same thing whit `hi.py`?

Comment: You mean like `./hi.py`?

Comment: Yes but that will work only if I'm my working directory is /home/user. I want to be able to do that from everywere

Comment: like when I use javac I don't need to go to /bin and do a ./javac I can do that from every working directory

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/451902/add-to-path-only-sh-file-not-a-dir, http://askubuntu.com/questions/440691/add-a-binary-to-my-path, and http://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application/script:

1. needs to be in one of the directories in PATH (according to [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) you should use `/usr/local/bin`)
2. needs to be executable and, if it is an interpreted script, have a shebang (e.g. `#!/bin/sh` for shell scripts, `#!/usr/bin/env python2` for python scripts).